# Modal with Delete confirmation in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I wanted a Custom JS popup modal to ask confirmation before deleting the user. Here I'm providing a solution for what I was not able to find anywhere.

Comment: While sharing your own knowledge can be valuable the question itself must be an actual answerable question and not just a lead on for whats more of a tutorial/blog post. This question doesn't actually tell us anything except that you're really bad at searching for information.

Comment: As a question its also a dupe for tons of questions -many which are closed as off topic.

Comment: thanks @max for your valuable comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing all the required gems for bootstrap, javascript and jquery make following changed in respective files to display modal on deleting a user.

users_controller.rb

Create admin folder in controllers folder under.In this folder create users_controller.rb file.  In this file create an action as follow:

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def delete_modal
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
  ...
end
```

routes.rb

In this file make a member route for resources :users

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :users do
    member do
      get 'delete_modal'
    end
  end
end
```

delete_modal.js.erb

In views folder create users folder. In this folder create delete_modal.js.erb file. In this file write the following code to render partial witch contains modal and show it:

```
$('#open-delete-modal').append("<%=j render(partial: 'delete_modal', locals: { user: @user}) %>");
$('#delete-modal').modal('show')
```

where "j" represents parsing of java script.

_delete_modal.html.erb

In same users folder under views folder create a partial file _delete_modal.html.erb and write the following bootstrap modal html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="delete-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Prompt</h5>
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Are you sure to delete the record?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <%= link_to 'Delete', admin_user_path(user), method: :delete, class:"btn btn-dark" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

where  id="delete-modal" will let jquery access this modal.
and link_to tag is a delete button to delete a record.

index.html.erb

In same users folder under views folder create index.html.erb. this file will display all users record. Here on delete button we want to open a modal for delete confirmation. For that write this:

```
<div id='open-delete-modal'></div>
```

this id will let jQuery know where we want to display modal.